# ACT-R is not reloading models

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, lisp-box

I am working through the tutorial files included with the ACT-R Standalone Windows distribution. This isn't part of any academics assignment; I'm working on this to learn cognitive modeling and writing production systems. I am using Lispbox, an EMACS-SLIME-LISP bundle to write my cognitive models. The distro and lispbox reside on my flash drive. Finally, the distro uses Clozure Common Lisp.

The problem is that whenever I try to reload a model after making changes, ACT-R gives me this error:

```
Error Reloading:
#|warning: no load file recorded |#
#|warning: cannot use reload |#
```

It only does this for my unit 2 assignment model. Not any other model, including the one I have written in unit 1.

Now this is a big issue for me - instead of simply pressing "reload" on ACT-R's GUI, I'm forced to close ACT-R entirely and open it again *every* time I want to reload the model.

I'm thinking this is a problem with EMACS. I have tried reinstalling ACT-R, and deleting any .lisp~ files or anything else that Emacs has saved in addition to the file I wrote. I still get this error.

Could you please help me understand what's going on and how I can fix this if it ever arises again in the future? I would like to get back to working on my assignment as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I have emailed the creator of ACT-R; He told me that I must include the statement

```
(clear all)
```

at the beginning of every file, so the software uses the most up-to-date file when reloading.